# Can´t install Intel OpenCL SDK in Windows 8

Tags: windows, visual-studio, opencl, intel

I´m trying to install sdk of open cl sdk of Intel in my machine to use in Visual Studio 2010 or 2012, but when I install, the instalation rollback and didn´t install when I select to integrate with any version of Visual Studio, but if I didn´t select any option to integrate it install.

So I need to use this in Visual Studio for my class.

I changed the permission folder in Windows 8 and it didn´t works.

I´m using windows 8 single language 64 bits, actually using Visual Studio C++ Express 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just read a blog post on a similar topic. The fix there might work for you as well. I haven't tried it myself since I'm not having this problem.

Please see: https://anteru.net/2013/11/01/2204/

In this case the blogger was not able to install the latest Intel OpenCL SDK after upgrading to Windows 8.1

Comment: I found problems to run a application that came with SDK, but I uninstall my driver video and put one new and open, but still not installing when I select to integrate with visual studio, I´m going to read what you told.